# Child element exceeds the length of parent div

Tags: html

My child div exceeds the length of the length of my parent div and I don't know how to fix it. I need that if the `<p>` element exceeds the length of the parent div then the exceed length should be hidden or not displayed in the div.

Please find the same problem:

```css
#parent {
  border: 3px solid #f0f
}

#child2 {
  padding: 50px;
  background: cyan;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child2">
    <p>
      Hi! 50px of padding, and it's working!
    </p>
    <p>
      Hi! 50px of padding, and it's working!
    </p>
    <p>
      Hi! 50px of padding, and it's working!
    </p>
    <p>
      Hi! 50px of padding, and it's working!
    </p>
    <p>
      Hi! 50px of padding, and it's working!
    </p>
    <p>
      Hi! 50px of padding, and it's working!
    </p>
    <p>
      Hi! 50px of padding, and it's working!
    </p>
    <p>
      Hi! 50px of padding, and it's working!
    </p>
    <p>
      Hi! 50px of padding, and it's working!
    </p>
    <p>
      Hi! 50px of padding, and it's working!
    </p>
    <p>
      Hi! 50px of padding, and it's working!
    </p>
    <p>
      Hi! 50px of padding, and it's working!
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't set the `height`. That's your problem. Removing the `height: 30px;` will make it work. If you want it hidden, use `overflow: auto;` or `overflow: scroll;`

Comment: You are welcome! `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't set the `height`. That's your problem. Removing the `height: 30px;` will make it work. If you want it hidden, use `overflow: auto;` or `overflow: scroll;`.

Here's a snippet that gives you a desired solution:

```css
#parent {
  border: 3px solid #f0f
}

#child2 {
  padding: 50px;
  background: cyan;
  height: 30px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child2">
    <p>
      Hi! 50px of padding, and it's working!
    </p>
    <p>
      Hi! 50px of padding, and it's working!
    </p>
    <p>
      Hi! 50px of padding, and it's working!
    </p>
    <p>
      Hi! 50px of padding, and it's working!
    </p>
    <p>
      Hi! 50px of padding, and it's working!
    </p>
    <p>
      Hi! 50px of padding, and it's working!
    </p>
    <p>
      Hi! 50px of padding, and it's working!
    </p>
    <p>
      Hi! 50px of padding, and it's working!
    </p>
    <p>
      Hi! 50px of padding, and it's working!
    </p>
    <p>
      Hi! 50px of padding, and it's working!
    </p>
    <p>
      Hi! 50px of padding, and it's working!
    </p>
    <p>
      Hi! 50px of padding, and it's working!
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```